# How to convert Int to Double in Swift playground?

Tags: ios, swift

I made a new Playground and wrote the code as following.

```
var value = 33 //This will make an integer type of value variable with value 33

value = 22.44 //This doesn't execute as its assigning Double/Float value to an integer.
```

I tried

```
1. 
value = Double(value)
value = 44.55 //Error here

2. 
value = Double(33.44) //Error here too.

3.
value : Double = 33.22 //Error here too.
```

Now what should I do to assign floating point to value.

NOTE: I am at learning level in Swift.

Thanks.

Comment: try var value = 33.0

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Declaring `var value = 33` will infer the type of value as `Int`. If you want to assign 33 and make `value` as Float or Double, you have to declare the type `var value : Double = 33` or convert 33 to a Double while assign `var value = Double(33)`.

Comment: What If I first assign 33, it will be a integer. and later I can't convert that data type to Double?

Comment: No, you can't convert a declared `Int` to a `Double`. Swift is a statically typed language, once a variable has a type, it cannot be changed.

Comment: Okay dear. a strong lack in language, still Apple says its flexible ;)

Comment: Can't you just assign the `Double` value to another variable? There are good reasons why static languages work in that way.

Comment: I can, but I was practicing, so I thought to do so ... :)

Answer (score 1):

You must set the data type within the variable declaration.

```
var value: Double = 33
```

But you could also do it like so:

```
var value: Double
value = 33
```

Defining it as a var will make the variable mutable, so after defining you can change the value

```
value = 33.2
value = 46.1
```

If you are only defining a constant, or a variable which does not need to change, you're best defining it like so:

```
let value: Double = 33.2
```

If you need this to be an Int for any reason at some point you can pass it through to a function or define it like so:

```
let intValue = Int(value)
```

Answer (score 0):

With the first line

```
var value = 33
```

you created a variable with the type of `Int` (because `33` is an integer literal). After that, you cannot assign any other type to that, only `Int`s. You should create another variable to store the result of the convertion.